# AmpScript using Variables and IIF Statement

Tags: variables, salesforce, iif, ampscript

%%=IIF((@Loantype=="VA"),CONCAT("help",(@CurrentMonthlyPayment_PI_MIP),""),"")=%%

What is wrong with this? These are already established variables in my template and Data Extension. Just wondering what I am doing wrong. I'm no expert by any means but I've been taking others code before me and just winging it if I'm being honest.

%%=IIF((@Loantype=="VA"),CONCAT("help",(@CurrentMonthlyPayment_PI_MIP),""),"")=%%
It keeps spitting an error saying I need to close a ).

This one is empty but with no error.
%%=IIF((@Loantype=="VA"),CONCAT(@CurrentMonthlyPayment_PI_MIP),"")=%%

This function works but it is not what I am trying to accomplish. I just used it as a base because it works and it uses variables in an IIF statement
%%=IIF(not empty(@BorrowerFirstName),CONCAT("Dear ", Propercase(@BorrowerFirstName), ","),"")=%%

Comment: post on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ too. more admins and MC specialists over there. Technically stackoverflow is for code-related problems. This is "just" config.